# date_query seems to be ignored by wp_query

Tags: wp-query, query, date

I'm altering my main wp_query in a pre_get_posts filter in order to improve my site search capabilities.

I've successfully achieved searching in taxonomies, but I fail when it comes to the post date ranges. Even the example query in the wp docs don't work for me.

```
$datequery = array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    );
$query->set('date_query', $datequery);
```

If I print_r the content of `$wp_query->request`, it doesn't contain anything related with dates, except for the ordering.

What's wrong?

PS: WP 3.6.1

Comment: Wrong is your WP version, because date_query will be added only in the WP 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `date_query`, not yet, or not in your version of WordPress. [From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters):

```
date_query (array) - Date parameters (available with Version 3.7).
```

3.7 has not been released, though [you can get it via SVN](http://wordpress.org/download/svn/), and you are using 3.6.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete.